# Javascript JSON parse error with Latex Formular

Tags: latex, jsonparser

I want to create JSON string api with latex formular, I found that `JSON.parse`

can not parse Latex formular like this:

```
{"id":19,"question":"<p>$\\left\\{ \\begin{align}</p><p>&nbsp;&amp; 2\\left| x-1 \\right|+\\frac{y}{x+y}=6 \\\\ </p><p>&nbsp;&amp; \\left| x-1 \\right|+\\frac{x}{x+y}=1 \\\\ </p><p class=\"ql-align-justify\">\\end{align} \\right.$"}
```

Sample test

```
t = '{"id":19,"question":"<p>$\\left\\{ \\begin{align}</p><p>&nbsp;&amp; 2\\left| x-1 \\right|+\\frac{y}{x+y}=6 \\\\ </p><p>&nbsp;&amp; \\left| x-1 \\right|+\\frac{x}{x+y}=1 \\\\ </p><p class=\"ql-align-justify\">\\end{align} \\right.$"}'
JSON.parse(t)
```

Error message `Uncaught SyntaxError: Bad escaped character in JSON at position 26 (line 1 column 27)`

Tried with online JSON lint / validator, input string is true json string.